# How to send request with duplicate data in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

i need to send request with duplicate in data. As i heard i cant send duplicates because requests use dict and i cant get duplicates in dict.

What i need to get (sniffed log from fiddler)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJm0Evrx7PZJnQkNw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryJm0Evrx7PZJnQkNw
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="qwe.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

example content of file qwe.txt blablabla
```

my script:

```
requests.post(url, files={'file[]': open('qwe.txt','rb'), 'file[]':''})
```

=> got only this (log from Fiddler). One file[] disappears.

```
--a7fbfa6d52fc4ddd8b82ec8f7055c88b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="qwe.txt"

example content of file qwe.txt blablabla
```

i tried:

```
requests.post(url, data={"file[]":""},files={'file[]': open('qwe.txt','rb')})
```

but its without: filename="" and content-type

```
--a7fbfa6d52fc4ddd8b82ec8f7055c88b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"

--a7fbfa6d52fc4ddd8b82ec8f7055c88b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="qwe.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

example content of file qwe.txt blablabla
```

There is any way to add this manually in python-requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with `requests` 1.1.0 you can use a list of tuples instead of a dict to pass as the `files` parameter. The first element in each tuple is the name of the multipart form filed, which can be followed either by the content, or by another tuple containing filename, content and (optionally) content type, so in your case:

```
files = [('file[]', ("", "", "application/octet-stream")),
         ('file[]', ('qwe.txt', open('qwe.txt','rb'), 'text/plain'))]
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

should produce the result you described.